# How can I clear an array when I load the page?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, page-refresh

I have an HTML Form that connects to a MySQL Database and Filters the database based on user input, the user inputs their criteria into a text box and clicks a button that will then submit the information into an array and then the data from the database appears on a separate page. Once I am done viewing the database data on that separate page, I then click the back button on my browser, but the array is not empty. However whenever I refresh the page the array clears! How can I make the HTML document refresh ONE TIME once the page has loaded?

Comment: What do you mean by submitting the information into an array? How/why do you use the array?

Comment: This is due to browser cache (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)